# How to set dynamic routing in React with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to add a dynamic route to the following routes, but whenever I am adding it. My CSS is not loading. I am using `react-router-dom 4.1.1`

I am directly importing my CSS in `index.html` page. I have only one `css` file which I am directly importing in `index.html`.
I am getting this error on console.

`Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:`

And my CSS file path is also getting changed

`http://localhost:3000/users/css/demo.css`

which should be like this

`http://localhost:3000/css/demo.css`

This means users is also getting added to the CSS file path.

Here is my routes:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink }from 'react-router-dom';

class Routes extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
      <div>
        <header className="header-basic">
          <div className="header-limiter">
            <h1><NavLink exact to="/">Test</NavLink></h1>
            <nav>
              <NavLink activeClassName="selected" exact to="/">Sign Up</NavLink>
              <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/event">Create Event</NavLink>
              <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/users">Admin Page</NavLink>
              <NavLink activeClassName="selected" to="/eventlist">Events List</NavLink>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Registration} />
        <Route path="/users" component={AdminPage} />
        <Route path="/event" component={Event} />
        <Route path="/eventlist" component={EventList} />
        # When I am adding here I am able to get to the page but all my CSS is not loading. In fact plain text is coming.
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

I want to add another route:

```
<Route path="/users/:user" component={User} />
```

`Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "affairal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.46.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

}

Comment: why you want to add dynamically any specific reason? didn't get this *It's coming below every component* ?

Comment: I want to load different user page on click of their ID. which is on /users page. so I want to load /users/:user from here i will get to know which user

Comment: Did you try adding the dynamic route inside the AdminPage component?

Comment: No, I haven't tried adding inside AdminPage component.

Comment: The way you have it right now, when you enter url "/users/5", both "/users" and "/users/:id" are matched. Both components will appear.

Comment: @MohamedIsmat I think there is a `exact` keyword: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool

Comment: Yeah but it's not used in this example. Both components will render